# how to access context from inside class component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

i am trying to read a property on my context. i need to read it from inside a class that extends component. from reading different posts it seems the usual way to do it is to expose the consumer / provider inside the render, but i am not using the class to render anything.

others say that i should give the class my context type via a static contextType = myContext.

BUT, when i do this, i get the cannot access property before initialization...

```
// other imports
import { Context } from "../context/authContext";

export default class FLClient extends Component {
    static contextType = AuthContext;

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        // do stuff with context props
```

how can i do this without propdrilling ?

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed use the contextType static property. However, there might be a typo in your code. The context should be imported as Context, but you're using AuthContext in static contextType = AuthContext; Try this instead and see if it works,

```js
import { Context as AuthContext } from "../context/authContext";

export default class FLClient extends Component {
    static contextType = AuthContext;

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        // access context using this.context
        const authContextValue = this.context;
        // do stuff with context props
    }

    // rest of your component logic
}
```